# Airwave Aruba API , How to generate Report ID

Tags: networking, aruba

I am trying to automate reports generation for aruba.

This endpoint generates the report -:

```
https://{{host}}/latest_report.xml?definitions_edit=1&id=42
```

this requires report ID. now to generate the report ID we need login to GUI. I want to do this through API, I couldn't find anything on google/youtube/official documentation.

Is it possible to do so? if yes can someone help with the endpoint.
I tried to work with "/reports_definition" endpoint but I couldn't find the right parameters to pass in Body.